# How can i change the property "visible" of a a-image with a js script?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I'm trying to change the property "visible" when my var *n* is equal to 1. Something on my code is not ok, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
<a-assets>
        <img id="txt-image" src="/img/txt.png">
        <img id="btn-image" src="/img/btn.png">
</a-assets>
```

```
<a-image src="#btn-image" position="0.35666 1.90018 -1.26009" geometry="" scale="0.361 0.09143 0.14667" rotation="10.87 0 0" class="clickable" cursor-listener></a-image>

<a-image src="#txt-image" position="0.1901 1.80662 -1.24519" geometry="" scale="0.85378 0.04647 0.34688" rotation="10.87 0 0" material="" visible="false" cursor-listener></a-image>
```

```
var n = 0;

AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
init: function () {
  let text = document.querySelector("#txt-image");
  this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    n += 1;
    console.log(n);

    if(n == 1){ 
        text.setAttribute("visible", true);
    }
    if(n == 2){
        window.open('portfolio.html', '_blank');
    }

  });
}
});
```

I'm not having console errors until now, so I really don't know what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to change the visibility on the asset item, not the `<a-image>`.

You can create an `id` exclusive for the `<a-image>` entity, and provide it to the querySelector.

---

To anwser the topic - you can switch the visibility with `setAttribute`:

```
var isVisible = true // or false
element.setAttribute("visible", isVisible);
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xneL5prq/).

Comment: Thank you so much Adam! Sorry for the common error. I'm a newbie  a-frame dev :)

Comment: Glad i could help, have fun with a-frame !